# Sharepoint REST results set - how to use a variable as the column name (field name)?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have been using the following function to access a REST result set of a REST query:

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
                    $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                        alert(item.columnName); //DO WHATEVER HERE
                    });
                }
            },
```

I would like to know - is there a way I can access a particular field based on a variable in the function? Say, we have a string variable called "FieldName" with a value of "Woosh", and I don't know that before I execute the REST query, can I actually do something to show that particular field (i.e. the same as retrieving item.Woosh in the example above)?

I tried using `item.get_item(FieldName)` assuming FieldName is the variable containing the name of the field to pull, but it is not quite working. Wondering if there are other alternatives to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) which allows you to use the name of the property as a string, so assuming `columnName` is a string variable:

```
success: function (data) {
  if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
      alert(item[columnName]); //DO WHATEVER HERE
    });
  }
},
```